# Child process and C stream buffering

Tags: c, process, buffer, stdout

I have a recursive function which is called in `main`. It creates several child processes using `fork` and print some information about them. To print properly I can use flush, but I would like to try `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` instead. Child process gets a copy of the parent memory, so will it be enough to call `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` once in `main` before calling recursive function or should I call `setbuf` for every child process?

I noticed that calling `setbuf` only in `main` prints right messages, but I am not sure if it is a coincidence or not.

Comment: Do you want the output in the main parent process to be unbuffered as well, or only in the child processes? And why is it even a problem to call `setvbuf` in the child process? It's not going to matter code-wise as it will still have only one single call.

Comment: And what is the problem you have with the output in the child processes? Why do you need to call `fflush` or make the streams unbuffered? Perhaps your actual question should be about that problem instead?

Comment: Yes, I want all processes output be unbuffered. I haven't realy thougth about calling it form child process. The question which bothers me is if the child processes will inherit and be unbuffered after calling it in main?

Comment: If you really need the child processes to have unbuffered output (which, I'm sorry to say, I honestly question the need for) then the first thing you do in the child process, directly after `fork`, just call `setvbuf`.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` is the first process is enough to make `stdout` unbuffered in all child processes created by `fork()` because the stream bufferisation is all handled inside the process in user space.

Yet if some of the child processes use `exec` to run another executable, the buffering scheme for the new executable will be initialized to the default one: line buffered if `stdout` is attached to a terminal and fully buffered if writing to a regular file.

> I noticed that calling `setbuf` only in `main` prints right messages, but I am not sure if it is a coincidence or not.

Indeed all child processes should have their `stdout` stream unbuffered so no manual flushing is required.  Note however that the output from different children can occur in any order and even get mixed.  Buffering the output and using `fflush()` appropriately might reduce this occurrence but does not guarantee atomic output.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard library buffering is inside the process, so child processes created with `fork` will inherit the results of calling `setbuf(stdout, NULL)`.